# "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" when passing parameters to powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, cmd

I'm trying to parse some parameters to a script I'm running in powershell.
But I'm getting errors while executing the script saying they are empty.

Im starting the process like this:

```
string input1 = "Powershell.exe -File " + Config.Directory + "/ICS.ps1" + " -toggle '" + toggle + "' -par1 '" +
                par1 + "' -par2 '" + par2 + "' -connectionInterface '" + connectionInterface + "'";

//(for readability) input1 will look something like this:
//Powershell.exe -File map/to/ICS.ps1 -toggle 'EnableSharing' -par1 '0' -par2 '1' -connectionInterface 'Ethernet'

string[] output = CmdProcess.Exec(input1);
```

`CmdProcess.Exec` is a method i created to quickly run a cmd process.
it works like this

```
public static string[] Exec(params string[] parameters)
    {
        Process cmd = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                Verb = "runas",
                FileName = @"cmd.exe",
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
            }
        };
        cmd.Start();

        foreach (string parameter in parameters)
        {
            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(parameter);
        }
        cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
        return Regex.Split(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(), "\r\n");
    }
```

the reason i use cmd to execute powershell is because i tried it with a powershell instance* but that crashed for an unknown reason on really fast computers (while it runs normally if you run it manually).
*`System.Management.Automation.Powershell`

in the script i wrote this: (At the beginning of the script)

```
Param( [string]$toggle, [string]$par1, [string]$par2, [string]$connectionInterface )
```

But it gives an error the params are null :

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\Jeremy\AppData\Roaming\HotspotLauncher\ICS.ps1:10 char:1
+ $config.$toggle($par1)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

I get error's like this with all the params. not just `$toggle` or `$par1`.

---

I tried running `Powershell.exe` and `-File .....` seperatly but that caused my thread to hang.

---

Also I'm 100% sure `toggle`, `par1` and the rest (In the C# code) arent null themselves

---

I also tried adding `[CmdletBinding()]` before the `params` in the script but that did nothing :

```
[CmdletBinding()]Param( [string]$toggle, [string]$par1, [string]$par2, [string]$connectionInterface )
```

---

Here is the powershell script:

```
[CmdletBinding()]Param( [string]$toggle, [string]$par1, [string]$par2, [string]$connectionInterface )

regsvr32 hnetcfg.dll /s
$m = New-Object -ComObject HNetCfg.HNetShare
$m.EnumEveryConnection |% { $m.NetConnectionProps.Invoke($_) }
$c = $m.EnumEveryConnection |? { $m.NetConnectionProps.Invoke($_).Name -eq $connectionInterface }
$config = $m.INetSharingConfigurationForINetConnection.Invoke($c)
Write-Output $config.SharingEnabled
Write-Output $config.SharingConnectionType
$config.$toggle($par1)

$m2 = New-Object -ComObject HNetCfg.HNetShare
$m2.EnumEveryConnection |% { $m2.NetConnectionProps.Invoke($_) }
$c2 = $m2.EnumEveryConnection |? { $m2.NetConnectionProps.Invoke($_).DeviceName -Match 'Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter' }
$config2 = $m2.INetSharingConfigurationForINetConnection.Invoke($c2)
Write-Output $config2.SharingEnabled
Write-Output $config2.SharingConnectionType
$config2.$toggle($par2)
```

This script enables/disables Internet sharing for the `$connectionInterface` which could be something like Ethernet or Wifi, and set it to public (`$par1`) / or nothing if it has to be disabled.
and does the same for microsoft hostednetwork and set it to private (`$par2`).

Answer (score 1):

Don't fork a new process with `powershell.exe` - use [the API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation(v=vs.85).aspx) instead:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Management.Automation;
//...

using(PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    ps.AddScript(Path.Combine(Config.Directory, "ICS.ps1"))
        .AddParameter("toggle", toggle)
        .AddParameter("par1", par1)
        .AddParameter("par2", par2)
        .AddParameter("connectionInterface", connectionInterface);
    Collection<PSObject> results = ps.Invoke();
}
```

Remember to add a reference to the `System.Management.Automation.dll` assembly to your project

Comment: I just tried it, but i still get the error that they are null. I checked again if `toggle` and `par1` and `par2` aren't null themselves but they are fine.

Comment: @Jeremy Can you post the PowerShell script itself in the question?

Comment: @Jeremy Your problem seems to be that `$config` is `$null`, ie. `$m.INetSharingConfigurationForINetConnection.Invoke($c)` doesn't return anything

Comment: You're right, it does return `$null`. I was wrong, the params arren't `$null`. they work correctly. but at line 5, when i check the `$connectionInterface` it returns null even though `$connectionInterface` isn't null AND it does have the correct value.Example:  in the list of connection interfaces there is one named "Ethernet", and `$connectionInterface` is "Ethernet", but It still returns `$null`. But if i were to change `$connectionInterface` to `'Ethernet'` it works

Comment: FYI:If you have possible concurency (multiple execution in parallel) be carefull, using the method above.  All your Powershell instances will be in the same process and share all global Powershell variable/configs, so be sure your script does use and modify those per instance.  Learned this the hard way :(